# MongoDB $expr get records with specified year

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm migrating my Node.js/Express app to Azure and had to switch from MongoDB to Cosmos API. I am having trouble getting this script to work. I’ve tried several methods and samples, but none worked for me.

Versions:

- MongoDB version v4.2.2
- Node v14.16.0

This is the error I’m getting now:

> (node:124032) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: unknown operator: $expr

Here is the code that causing the issue. What am I doing wrong?

```
queryObj = 
    {
      '$and': [
        { devType: 'Web Development' },
        { category: 'Project' },
        { assignedDev: '5ad676ca8341f186e8ad7764' },
        {
          '$expr': { '$eq': [ { '$year': '$createdOn' }, '2018' ] }
        },
        { status: { '$in': 'Completed' } }
      ]
    };

Project.find(queryObj, {id:1, submitterID:1, submitterFullName:1, title:1, devType:1, desiredDate:1, priority:1, category:1, createdOn:1, status:1})
    .populate({
      path: 'assignedDev',
      select: {fName:1, lName:1},
      options: { lean: true}
    }).lean().limit(500).then(project => {
       console.log(project);
    });
```

Comment: the query looks good, out of scope correct the things 1) `{ status: { '$in': ['Completed'] } }` in requires array but you have passed string only. 2) change `'2018'` to `2018` just pass in number because $year will return year in number.

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/34251223-support-mongodb-s-expr-operation

Comment: Guess, I will have to wait for Azure to implement $expr function, thank you!